After adding the cloud_firestore package to my project this error appeared. App not running in IOS simulator
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 16 Pro Max in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.16.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/9/8/FirebaseAppCheckInterop/11.3.0/FirebaseAppCheckInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/9/8/FirebaseAppCheckInterop/11.2.0/FirebaseAppCheckInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/9/8/FirebaseAppCheckInterop/11.1.0/FirebaseAppCheckInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/9/8/FirebaseAppCheckInterop/11.0.0/FirebaseAppCheckInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/7/FirebaseAuthInterop/11.3.0/FirebaseAuthInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/7/FirebaseAuthInterop/11.2.0/FirebaseAuthInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/7/FirebaseAuthInterop/11.1.0/FirebaseAuthInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/7/FirebaseAuthInterop/11.0.0/FirebaseAuthInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/7/f/FirebaseCoreExtension/11.3.0/FirebaseCoreExtension.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/7/f/FirebaseCoreExtension/11.2.0/FirebaseCoreExtension.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/7/f/FirebaseCoreExtension/11.1.0/FirebaseCoreExtension.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/7/f/FirebaseCoreExtension/11.0.0/FirebaseCoreExtension.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/9/1/FirebaseCoreInternal/11.3.0/FirebaseCoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/9/1/FirebaseCoreInternal/11.2.0/FirebaseCoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/9/1/FirebaseCoreInternal/11.1.0/FirebaseCoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/9/1/FirebaseCoreInternal/11.0.0/FirebaseCoreInternal.podspec.json exists! 

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A BoringSSL-GRPC
  A Firebase
  A FirebaseAppCheckInterop
  A FirebaseAuth
  A FirebaseAuthInterop
  A FirebaseCore
  A FirebaseCoreExtension
  A FirebaseCoreInternal
  A FirebaseFirestore
  A FirebaseFirestoreInternal
  A FirebaseSharedSwift
  A Flutter
  A GTMSessionFetcher
  A GoogleUtilities
  A RecaptchaInterop
  A abseil
  A cloud_firestore
  A firebase_auth
  A firebase_core
  A gRPC-C++
  A gRPC-Core
  A leveldb-library
  A nanopb
  A path_provider_foundation

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.36)
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /opt/homebrew/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/rf/5bxv_hj101g5t_lglvj7hpp80000gn/T/d20241020-12805-m9ygc0 --template=

[!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
[!] /opt/homebrew/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/rf/5bxv_hj101g5t_lglvj7hpp80000gn/T/d20241020-12805-m9ygc0 --template=

Cloning into '/var/folders/rf/5bxv_hj101g5t_lglvj7hpp80000gn/T/d20241020-12805-m9ygc0'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 5407 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:144:in `rescue in execute_command'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:141:in `execute_command'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:175:in `block in executable'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:107:in `block in clone'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:175:in `block in ui_sub_action'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:174:in `ui_sub_action'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:105:in `clone'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:73:in `download!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:83:in `block in download'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:159:in `block in ui_action'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:158:in `ui_action'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:81:in `download'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:110:in `download_source'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:77:in `download_request'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:256:in `download'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:239:in `block in uncached_pod'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:266:in `in_tmpdir'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:238:in `uncached_pod'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_downloader.rb:69:in `download!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:117:in `download_source'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:67:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:621:in `install_source_of_pod'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:539:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:538:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `install_pod_sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:258:in `block in download_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:257:in `download_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Cloning into '/var/folders/rf/5bxv_hj101g5t_lglvj7hpp80000gn/T/d20241020-12805-m9ygc0'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 5407 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 16 Pro Max.
Exited (1).
My laptop is Mac M1. How can I solve this problem once and for all?

I got the same issue. I shifted my internet connection to mobile data from Wifi and it install the package successfully. I do not know the exact reason but it works for me.
Using Mac M1.
